# Deploying a NetBeans application with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am attempting to build an application in NetBeans that can be deployed to and end user. I am still pretty new to deploying projects and this is by far the most complicated one I have done so please bear with me. I currently have a working application in NetBeans which utilizes JDK 15 and JavaFX 15. As long as I run things inside of NetBeans everything works as intended. I have reached a point where I want to make sure I can distribute this application outside of NetBeans. To this end I did some searching and found the following tutorial.

https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

I was able to follow the tutorial and build the example. The build works in NetBeans, I am able to run the executable jar file in the dist folder from the command line, and I am able to run the jar file by executing it from the file explorer. Now when I attempt to do the same process with my own project I run into the following errors.

1. When I attempt to run the jar file in the dist folder absolutely nothing happens.
2. When I attempt to run the jar file from the command line using the command

java -jar "C:\Workspace\HandyAndyVersion1_2\dist\HandyAndyVersion1_2.jar"

I receive the following error,

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.

I am currently under the assumption that the first problem is a by product of the second. If anybody has a solution to this problem or any ideas on what I could have configured wrong please let me know and thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To package a Java desktop application these days, you should be using the [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/index.html) tool and optionally the [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) tool.  These will generate a JRE image that is packaged with the application and contains the modules you need.

I suspect the issue you are running into is that the native libraries for JavaFX are not present.  Most distributions of JDK 15 do not contain the JavaFX modules, though some do. (See the Full and FX bundles of the JDK from [Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk) and [Bellsoft](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/)).  I find it is easier to use a JDK with JavaFX bundled rather than have to manage a separate module path during development for the jmod files of JavaFX, but that is another option.  Either method can be used with jlink to create a suitable JRE for your application that includes the JavaFX modules.

Comment: Thank you for the information and I will look into those tools, however this doesn't really answer my question. I understand that the modules are not present native to JDK 15 which is why I have the JavaFX installed to a library which is currently being referenced in netbeans. Without this my application wouldn't run in the IDE itself. My confusion is as to why I can run the application in the IDE but cannot run the application outside of the IDE. What is the IDE doing internally that isn't being done elsewhere?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  Is this an Ant-based project (not recommended) or a Maven-based (better), or Gradle-based (also better)?  What does your Jar manifest look like?  What libraries are used and where are they located?  NetBeans is likely setting up the module path or class path differently, or passing other arguments to the JVM such as the folder to use for loading native libraries.